# Current time from GPRMC or GPZDA?

Tags: gps, nmea

In `GPRMC` there is a time field, called `fix time`. Can I consider this always the same as value from `GPZDA` time? Is there any possibility that when GPS device is configured to stream both `GPRMC` and `GPZDA` sentences, but their value will be different?

For my task it would be great if I could get time from `GPRMC`, however, I'm not sure if I can get consistent time value from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GPRMC works
```

Sentence Example

```
$GPRMC,040302.663,A,3939.7,N,10506.6,W,0.27,358.86,200804,,*1A
```

GPS devices are able to calculate the current date and time using GPS satellites (and not the computer's own clock, making it useful for synchronization). This word stores the current time, in UTC, in a compressed form "HHMMSS.XXX," where HH represents hours, MM represents minutes, SS represents seconds, and XXX represents milliseconds. The above value represents **04:03:02.663 AM UTC**.

http://www.codepedia.com/1/The+GPRMC+Sentence

```
GPZDA
```

Date & Time

UTC, day, month, year, and local time zone.

$--ZDA,hhmmss.ss,xx,xx,xxxx,xx,xx
hhmmss.ss = UTC
xx = Day, 01 to 31
xx = Month, 01 to 12
xxxx = Year
xx = Local zone description, 00 to +/- 13 hours
xx = Local zone minutes description (same sign as hours)

```
$GPGGA: Global Positioning System Fix Data
$GPGSV: GPS satellites in view
$GPGSA: GPS DOP and active satellites
$GPRMC: Recommended minimum specific GPS/Transit data
```

http://playground.arduino.cc/Tutorials/GPS

Comment: Confusing part is term `time of fix` for `GPRMC` in this link http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/

Comment: The key difference is that `GPRMC` is only sent after GPS has a location whereas `GPZDA` is sent as soon as time is received from a satellite. If you're only interested in time then use `GPZDA` so you'll still get time when the signal's too weak for a location fix.